# Move Python function to module without breaking compatibility or cyclic imports

Tags: python, python-import

Consider a Python module `fmod.py`:

```
def f(x):
     print(x)

def g():
     f("g")
```

Now the `g()` function should be moved to `gmod.py`:

```
import fmod

def g():
    fmod.f("g")
```

What is the best way to "keep" `fmod.g()` available for backward compatibility?

---

Attempt a)

```
from gmod import g

def f(x):
     print(x)
```

This will not work due to cyclic imports: `import gmod` from elsewhere fails.

---

Attempt b)

```
import gmod

def f(x):
     print(x)

g = gmod.g
```

This still does not work due to the same problem.

---

Attempt c)

```
def f(x):
     print(x)

def g(*args, **kwargs):
    import gmod
    return gmod.g(*args, **kwargs)
```

This works I think, but is rather complicated.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use your last option, or edit the `__init__.py` file this way:

```
import fmod
import gmod

fmod.g = gmod.g
```

Then you will be able to do:

```
import fmod

fmod.g('x')   #@UndefinedVariable
```